# Changing the font colour of data from database

Tags: php, html, css

Im still a beginner and i want to change the font colour.

`echo "<tr><td>" . $count . "</td><td>" . $row['c_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['invoice_number'] . "</td><td>" . date("d-m-Y",` `strtotime($row['purchase_date'])) . "</td>";`

i want it to be white instead of gray which is the default. The output is from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simple just

One way: add inline style where you want like `$cname` is coming from database then add inline style

```
<?php
$count = 10;
$cname = "Dupinder";

echo "<table><tr><td >" . $count . "</td><td style='color: red'>" . $cname . "</td></tr></table>";

?>
```

Second way:
create a css class

```
.dataDataBase
{
  color: red;
}
```

and add class to thode `TD` which contains data from database :)

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $count . "</td><td class='dataDataBase'>" . $row['c_name'] . "</td><td class='dataDataBase'>" . $row['invoice_number'] . "</td><td class='dataDataBase'>" . date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['purchase_date'])) . "</td>";
```

this should work fine

Comment: I tried the first one, I'm using " " instead of ' '. That's why it won't work.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a CSS file you would need to add this for the right HTML tag:

```
td {
    color : white;
}
```

Or as an alternative you could add this to your php:

```
<td style="color:white;">
```

I used the td as an example, you will have to apply this to the one you need.